# BlackDuck scan integration for CI and CD deployment

Tags: jenkins, udeploy

Currently, we are using Jenkins for the build, Jfrog Artifactory to store all dependencies and udeploy to deploy the artifact to the server. In Jenkins, we have two plugins which will download all the dependencies and will deploy to release repo. Also, we have a plugin which will deploy the artifact to udeploy code station.

My question is how can I configure black duck scan in Jenkins and udeploy?

Answer (score 0):

Have udeploy act as a slave of jenkins.
Have black duck scan that folder path in the plugin job configuration.

This way you have latest source to scan.